# How to disable media controls on Windows 10 lock screen?

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen, playback

Windows 10 (I'm using version 1903) enables handling of media playback from the lock screen. It would be fine if it limited itself to audio explicitly played by me, but this has recently for some inexplicable reason started including YouTube videos when played on Chromium clones. I do not want other people to see what videos I have opened in background tabs when I'm away from the computer. How to disable this?

Comment: Start, Settings, Personalization, Lock Screen and turn the features off