# How to disable Windows lock screen showing sensitive content?

Tags: windows, windows-10, privacy

When you lock your Windows 10 workstation, the lock screen continues to show sensitive content:

[image]

You can then even resume playing the sensitive content.

How do you make locking the workstation lock the workstation?

---

It is part of the [**Windows.Media.Playback**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybacksession?view=winrt-22000) API of the Windows Runtime.

## Bonus

[image]

## Bonus Reading

- Microsoft Forums: [How Do I Disable the Media Controls That Appear On the Windows 10 Lock Screen?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-disable-the-media-controls-that-appear-on/b5e192b3-2c49-49f7-bcea-210068d770fb)
- Microsoft Forums: [Lock Screen Music Player](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/lock-screen-music-player/62460fd8-a320-48ec-924a-c08ade8fa78f)
- Microsoft Forums: [Media Controls on the Windows 10 Lock Screen](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/media-controls-on-the-windows-10-lock-screen/4ed282fc-55d0-45da-8f0c-efdb36548bca)
- Microsoft Forums: [Windows lock screen shows media player controls](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-lock-screen-shows-media-player-controls/50f42381-73f4-41e7-bc47-1f21f26c8f97)
- Superuser: [Winamp control on windows lock screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/323549/winamp-control-on-windows-lock-screen)
- Superuser: [How to disable media controls on Windows 10 lock screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/1509273/how-to-disable-media-controls-on-windows-10-lock-screen)
- Reddit: [How do I hide media controls on the lock screen?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/ema6i9/how_do_i_hide_media_controls_on_the_lock_screen/)
- Reddit: [How to turn off Windows 10's lockscreen media preview for Firefox 81+ (self.firefox)](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/jzejy3/how_to_turn_off_windows_10s_lockscreen_media/)
- [How do I turn off media controls on my lock screen?](https://quick-adviser.com/how-do-i-turn-off-media-controls-on-my-lock-screen/)
- [Disable media controls on the Windows 10 lock screen](https://bootpanic.com/disable-media-controls-on-the-windows-10-lock-screen/)
- [Windows lock screen shows media player controls](https://windowsbb.com/threads/496756/)

Comment: That is an example that is rude/abusive. Can't you find a better one?

Comment: Ideally i wouldn't have the screenshot at all.

Comment: In Settings, Personalization, Lock Screen turn OFF get fun facts. I get nothing on my Lock Screen Windows 10 or 11.  Also do not use your own picture - just one the bland Microsoft photos.

Comment: In Settings, Personalization, Lock Screen, **Fun Facts** already is turned off. That causes Windows to not show *"fun facts"* on the lock screen. That does not affect showing playing media.

Comment: Use al static photo as suggested. Windows 10, 11 for six years and nothing on my Lock Screen.

Comment: @John I am using a static photo. But i'm talking about the media controls. You're talking about the background image.

Comment: I don’t have any media controls on my Lock Screen. Other media controls in Windows are not related to Lock Screen.

Comment: Well that's excellent for you John. I'm glad you're not experiencing the problem. Thanks for sharing your experiences.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not controlled from the lock screen settings but from the application itself.

E.g. in Chrome it is an experimental feature. If the media content is coming from Chrome, in Chrome go to the experimental features page (chrome://flags), look for the Hardware Media Key Handling feature and disable it. I believe there's a similar procedure for Edge, but I've no idea if there are other applications that can "channel" media content to the lock screen or the procedure to disable them.